# what does the with-layout=gnu option do?

Tags: php, php5

I am compiling PHP 5.3.6 and the compile configure command I am using as a reference uses the --with-layout=GNU option.  I have done some research but I can't seem to find a detail answer.  Can someone please explain this option to me in detail and why one would use it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [the latest version of PHP's configure.in at the time of this answer](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/configure.in?revision=313575&view=markup), `--with-layout` is defined as:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH(layout, layout of installed files,
[  --with-layout=TYPE      Set how installed files will be laid out.  Type can
                          be either PHP or GNU [PHP]], PHP, no)

case $PHP_LAYOUT in
  GNU)
    oldstyleextdir=no
    ;;
  *)
    oldstyleextdir=yes
    ;;
esac
```

So if you choose `GNU`, it sets `oldstyleextdir=no`, otherwise `yes`. That helped me to find [this mail to php-dev in Dec 2005](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=113438913910662&w=2), which says in part:

> With that said, old style is:
>
> `$libdir/extensions/$extbasedir`
>
> while new style [GNU] is:
>
> `$libdir/$extbasedir`

Essentially, this option decides the location of the extensions directory (`EXTENSION_DIR`). Unfortunately, as the author of that mail notes, there isn't a lot of explanation about *why* the option was implemented – even in the [commit log entry](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=46762) – though I speculate it was to keep PHP in line with other "GNU/Linux" standards.

Answer (score 0):

[@fission’s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/293523/1018353) requires updating, but can’t be edited at present due to standoff between the site’s volunteers and owners.

For the current `configure.ac`, see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d65251e6e863684f8fc7ddc9c0fba7cf53483f7f/configure.ac#L926

The choice of PHP/GNU style affects more than just the extensions directory. The PHP style also puts manpages under `php/` instead of `share/`, thus breaking the [search path of the `manpath` utility](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/manpath.5.html#search%20path).